# Is there was a way to make an IOS app that could interact with NFC.?

Tags: ios, swift, nfc

So this isn't necessarily a code question, its more of a 'can it be done' question. I was wondering if there was a way to make an IOS app that could interact with NFC.

This a non-profit organization who organizes events like music concerts or playing ping pong for expats. To become a member user have to pay money for life time membership.

why user have to pay money?

To identify a user they have NFC reader at the entrance of the gate and in Bar for drinks. For this every user needs an card that contains NFC and the card interacts with NFC reader. 
So this is an charge for Membership Card. I want to reduce this cost by creating an IOS app.

What I need?

I want to create an IOS app(Using Swift & Firebase) to Identify user at entrance of the gate and in Bar to provide discounts. How can I achieve this?

I have read articles https://gototags.com/blog/apple-iphone-7-support-nfc-tags/
and googled it. But I don't find a perfect solution. Hope you guys shed some light.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the iPhone's NFC is very tightly locked down and you can't access it.  Besides, such a solution would restrict your membership to people who owned Apple Pay capable iPhones.  Maybe a more generic option like implementing a payment gateway that supports Apple Pay amongst other payment options would be better

Comment: Look on eBay; You can get NFC cards for $1 each.  Stickers for even less

Comment: Can apple pay allows to provide discounts at Bar?

Comment: You can try CoreNFC but it is only supported on iPhone 7 and above with iOS 11 and above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API for the NFC capabilities in iOS devices.  NFC is only used for ApplePay.

**Update** - [Core NFC](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc) in iOS 11 provides the ability for iPhone7 and later to read NDEF data from NFC tags.

Comment: Can apple pay allows to provide discounts at Bar?

Comment: not really; it is just a credit card payment.  It also requires the user to have a credit card issued by a bank that supports ApplePay

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this App using a Barcode?

Comment: Sure. You could have an app display a barcode on screen or you can use the iPhone camera to scan a barcode. If you are going to show a barcode on screen then you will need to scan it with either a CCD barcode scanner or another smart phone type device with a camera.

Comment: Please provide some more information. Any articles or website or video  on how to achieve this. I am also searching for this.